# Acomodar imagen detro de etiqueta img

Tags: html5, css3

Actualmente como me esta mostrando la foto se le corta la cabeza y estoy tratando de que me muestra toda la imagen correctamente .

Habrá alguna forma de acomodar la imagen bajandola o algo para que no se corte la cabeza?.Dejo el codigo y una imagen

```css
img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="/img/jugadores/5af0df8739be4.jpg" alt="" width="40">
```

[image: La imagen de lo que esta mostrando y quiero cambiar]

Comment: Hola con la etiqueta `padding-top: 25px;` puedes hacer bajar la imagen. es un ejemplo el dado, tienes que ir probando la cantidad de pixeles. saludos

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso, he buscado la imagen de un jugador que al usar las propiedades **CSS** que tenías definidas se me veía correctamente. Esto depende mucho de la imagen de la que partimos y de su proporción.

Yo te recomendaría que de a ser posible consiguieses las imágenes lo más cercanas a una proporción 5:4 (lo más cuadrada posible) y con el suficiente espacio encima y debajo del jugador para que al aplicarle el `border-radius` no ocurra lo que te está pasando.

Pero como no siempre se podrá conseguir una imagen que cumpla con esto, te planteo hacer lo siguiente:

```css
.contenedor-imagen-1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.contenedor-imagen-2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#imagen-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#imagen-2 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-left: -16px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-imagen-1">
<img id="imagen-1" src="https://d2yoo3qu6vrk5d.cloudfront.net/images/20180927173213/000_1639z4-482x320.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="contenedor-imagen-2">
<img id="imagen-2" src="https://d2yoo3qu6vrk5d.cloudfront.net/images/20180927173213/000_1639z4-482x320.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Lo que trato de hacer es una especie de "marco" que esté por delante de la imagen, para que dado el caso, podamos mover la imagen de abajo lo que necesitamos para dejarla encuadrada.

En mi ejemplo uso dos imágenes para tratar de ilustrar lo mejor posible el caso.

En la **primera**, la imagen se encuentra ocupando el 100% de su contenedor, ajustándose por defecto perfectamente, dado que la imagen cumple con los requisitos óptimos para que esto suceda.

En la **segunda** cambio el tamaño de la imagen para forzar un descuadre entre el marco y la imagen. Así que lo que hago es centrarla jugando con los márgenes para poder mover la imagen dentro del marco hasta colocarla lo más centrada posible.